# Debloating code with "using"

Tags: c#, coding-efficiency

I'm experimenting with shortening and refining my code as much as possible. One of the ideas I had involves returning a string from a single line of code, employing `using` to ensure that the accessed file becomes available again when the transaction is complete. My objective is to get as close to a single line of code as possible, however I am having trouble finding a way around the immutability of strings.

The following code is invalid:

```
string sample()
{
    try{ using( string example = (new StreamReader
                                 (new FileStream
                                 ("", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read),
                                 Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd())) }
    //I haven't quite worked out returning the value yet, but this is irrelevant here
}
```

The working code would be as follows:

```
string sample()
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    try{
        using(StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(fs);
        return rdr.ReadToEnd();
       }
}
```

I could easily simplify this by doing the following:

```
string sample()
    {
        try
        {
            return (new StreamReader(new FileStream
                                    ("", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read),
                                    Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
```

However, that may not close the file after the transaction is complete (if that's wrong please let me know). Is there a way to work around the immutability of a string here, or am I looking for the impossible?

Comment: why one liner is so much needed? you are loosing redability and ease of understanding

Comment: What is this code trying to do? Instead of clearing up bloat or simplifying anything, it's a *lot* harder to read. The `try` block doesn't seem to serve a  purpose either. Why not use a single `using`, or `File.ReadText`? This code is doing essentially what `File.ReadText` does

Comment: How about: `string content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename, Encoding.UTF8);`?

Comment: @Rahul I'm experimenting with the way C# works, more than creating something for actual use. I figure it's good practice to really udnerstand what I'm doing in the future.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What would multiple using statements accomplish here? I'm not quite understanding the purpose of using more than one

Comment: How C# works has nothing to do with shorthand code or code shortening. does it?

Comment: @Corak yes, but would this not leave the file locked after the transaction is complete?

Comment: @ScarySpice you should probably understand how C# works first before trying to "simplify things". Especially if you intend to use a `catch{}` to hide errors instead of handle them

Comment: @ScarySpice what transaction? The code you typed is roughly equivalent to what `ReadAllText` withouth the highly suspicious `try{}`

Comment: @Rahul not directly, but in the process of experimentation I'm finding that I'm learning a lot more about OO and C# from the various tangents that I take - and I'm learning faster by doing than by reading from a book

Comment: @ScarySpice - nope. It's basically a wrapper method around the correct `using`. Which was my point. Work with methods, that's what they're there for. Then everywhere you use that method, it's a "oneliner".

Comment: @ScarySpice in fact - [check the source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/file.cs#L830). It's a one-liner *already*

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Because I'm not specifically releasing the file after I've accessed it, how do I know that it is then subsequently available with read/write access without either a `using` statement or a `File.Close()` statement?

Comment: @Corak apart from argument checks, `File.ReadAllText` *is* a one-liner

Comment: @ScarySpice you mistake the **static** `File` class for something else entirely. Read the source. It's a one-liner already, it uses `using` correctly and returns the string in a single line

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Gotcha - this is excellent

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want a way to create an expression from a `using` statement. You can create a function:

```
public static T Use<TRec, T>(TRec resource, Func<TRec, T> f) where TRec : IDisposable
{
    using(resource) { return f(resource); }
}
```

then do

```
string s = Use(new StreamReader(new FileStream("", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), Encoding.UTF8), sr => sr.ReadToEnd());
```

Comment: That's how [File.ReadAllText](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/file.cs#L830) is written. No need for a `FileStream` either, it accepts a path

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - In this case yes, but it looks like this question is about `using` not reading text.

Comment: The question is about understanding C# syntax and simplifying code. This `Use` method isn't shorter or simpler than puting than writing `using(var s=new StreamReader(new FileStream("", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), Encoding.UTF8) return s.ReadToEnd()};`